# i'm not able to execute the following forecast npm which was already given in npmjs.com.

Tags: node.js

### output was shown as api not found.did not really the solution for it. please help

```js
var Forecast = require('forecast');
var forecast = new Forecast({
  service: 'forecast.io',
  key: 'your-api-key',
  units: 'celcius',  
  cache: true,       
  ttl: {            
    minutes: 27,
    seconds: 45
    }
});
forecast.get([12.9670,77.5873], function(err, weather) {
  if(err) return console.dir(err);
  console.dir(weather);
});
  
forecast.get([12.9670,77.5873], true, function(err, weather) {
  if(err) return console.dir(err);
  console.dir(weather);
});
```

##

Answer (score 1):

Node.JS is a server-side technology, not a browser technology. Thus, Node-specific calls, like require(), do not work in the browser.

See browserify or webpack if you wish to serve browser-specific modules from Node.

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js)

Comment: Is this a complete code? is there something that i need to add to it ?

Comment: Is complete, if you want to use it in a server. Like in node.js. After you install forecast with this command.
"npm install --save forecast"
You can't open this file with chrome for example, because it will not work.