# In my node js the requre function didn't work

Tags: html, node.js, node-modules

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'your_user',
  password: 'some_secret',
  database: 'the_app_database'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('You are now connected...')
});
```

i am new to nodejs. in my nodejs project the requre function didn't work what i do? i can't add jquery or any other thing. what is the problem why requre didnt work.can't connect to database mysql

Comment: what error u got?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Have u started your node application? Do u have node environment?

Comment: yes started node applaction ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [require is not defined? node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js)

Comment: _NodeJS is a server-side technology not client side_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js

Comment: missing script: build another error