# Trouble access node_modules on javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I have confusion about access node_modules that can be used in JavaScript. for this does anyone can give an example to call modul.export contained in the folder node_module (after install packet with NPM - nodejs) ?

tree structure file :
folder ethereum any folder node_modules , file index.html (for call module.export) , package-lock.json , package.json

package.json file :
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R-7-k4NCDcd933b4MXw1E7bncV7-w_6jVkdphq0_XaM/edit?usp=sharing)

so this way, I've installed "npm install web3". Now, when I call a function from web3 like for example in a program like this :

```
var Web3=require('web3');
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/metamask"));
    }
  console.log(web3);
```

Then output errors like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xzx8.png)

Comment: just run `example()` after your code?

Comment: I have edited the program example as above, I have also added an error output

Comment: The error reads `require is not defined` which implies that you're not running it in a `node` environment. How do you call your script ? Could you edit the answer with your `package.json` and directory structure?

Comment: I have added the one you requested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `web3` package can either be installed through `npm` with `npm install web3` or is exposed as a global `web3` if you import it like:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

It can either be run as a global exposed by the `<script></script>` tag or as a `node` package that needs to be bundled first.

Your error code `require is not defined` tells you that `node` is not running your code, but something else is consuming your code. Try to bundle your code to something the browser understands, or only use the global `web3` to interact with the package.

Read more about bundles here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/packages

Comment: for before I want to tell you that I have added <script> </ script>. The above is a small part of what I took. I'm trying also to use other nodes like web3-eth-accounts that are already in web3 using javascript . Is there a solution for this? but it seems like I am wrong to call the node huh ? :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are missing a big piece of the puzzle here.

You need to compile your code for the browser to be able to run it. Try reading up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js)

Comment: to understand, the above code is a package from ethereum (web3) :)