# How to include a css/js file from a node package?

Tags: html, css, node.js, npm

I have in stalled an [npm package](https://quilljs.com/). Now I want to include the css and js files in my html page by typing something like this:

```
      <link href="/root/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But the above path does not work. My html page is located at /var/www/html
What is the right way to do this. This is probably a duplicate but I am not able to find the answer.

Comment: can you edit your post to provide the file structure (preferably as text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your CSS and JS files are in the same directory (probably `src/app`) as your HTML files.

e.g.

```
src
 |
 | app
    |
    | css
    | js
   index.html
```

so the path to `index.html` in the web version is `/index.html`, and the path (relative to `index.html`) to the CSS folder is `./css`.

Here's a great [explanation of relative paths in node applications](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3244-non-module-file-paths-are-relative-to-the-working-directory-in-node-js.htm).

When using 3rd-party libraries such as CSS in node modules, you can use this in your stylesheet:

```
@import "~quill/dist/quill.snow";
```

You will also need to [require the module in your config file - see this discussion in GitHub for more info](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1789#issuecomment-250983832).

Comment: So I just copy the full package directory to my the website folder?

Comment: ah, if they are library CSS files that would be different

Comment: Sorry I don’t get that.

Comment: I mean if they are part of the npm package, you should use them from there. Just trying figure out how you should reference them, I'll be right back :) Are you using SCSS?

Comment: Thanks alot hope you will be able to help

Comment: Thank you but what if I want to add a .js file. When i try for example require(“/root/test.js”) it says that require is not definded

Comment: if you look at this answer on that github discussion, it shows how to do the requiring of js files in your config file. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1789#issuecomment-250955864

Comment: The `require is not defined` error is caused by trying to run your require file in the browser. See the answers to this question for what to do about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js/31931649

Comment: Tanks alot for helping!