# using npm module in renderer process of electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have installed Buffer module via `npm install Buffer` on my machine and I want to simply import it to the renderer process to use the Buffer

When I use this:

```
const Buffer = require('Buffer')
```

it says require is undefined.

None of the solutions on Stack Overflow are working.

Comment: use import instead, check it out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js

Comment: You may just need to set `nodeIntetration: true`. See [This explanation](https://jameshfisher.com/2020/10/15/how-does-require-work-in-electron/) and/or [this Stack Oveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `nodeIntegration` in your `BrowserWindow` settings set to `true` and `contextIsolation` set to `false` like so:

```js
new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences:  {
        nodeIntegration:  true,
        contextIsolation: false
    },
});
```

By default `nodeIntegration` is `false` which stops you from using NPM modules in the renderer-process, turning on `nodeIntegration` will fix this.

[Read more here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#nodejs-api)

> NOTE: To access the Node.js API from the Renderer process, you need to set the `nodeIntegration` preference to true and the `contextIsolation` preference to false.

**Disclaimer**, turning on `nodeIntegration` opens up security holes in your app. [See Zac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59888788/6577664) on how to fix them.

Comment: This answer opens up [security vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59888788/1837080) in your app.

Comment: @Zac Very true, your explanation of these security vulnerabilities is very comprehensive and I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer opens up security vulnerabilities, you should instead use preload scripts. preload scripts is a way of exposing some node.js functions to the renderer process without setting the nodeIntegration to true.
look at the [documentation about preload scripts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts) on [www.electronjs.org](http://www.electronjs.org).