# Import module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi

I am trying to import a node [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pigpio) in node 12.22.5

```
const Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio;
```

But I get an error telling me that require is not defined

Comment: Are you using ES6 module system in package.json?

Comment: Could you post the error it's giving you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require is not defined? Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js)

Comment: Difficult to help out without information on your environment (package.json, how the code is being run).

Answer (score -1):

For Raspberry Pi, you first need to install the module, then you can use it:

```
npm install pigpio
```