Contact form using reactjs
My form contains name email phoneno and message field and name and email mandatory now I want to accept the form using dynamodb ses and lambda function
{
  "errorType": "ReferenceError",
  "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
  "trace": [
    "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
    "    at file:///var/task/index.mjs:1:13",
    "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)",
    "    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)",
    "    at async _tryAwaitImport (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1008:16)",
    "    at async _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1057:86)",
    "    at async _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1081:16)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
  ]
}

My form contains name email phoneno and message field and name and email mandatory now I want to accept the form using dynamodb ses and lambda function
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const ses = new AWS.SES();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { name, email, phone, message } = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const id = `${Date.now()}`;

  const params = {
    TableName: 'ContactTable',
    Item: {
      id,
      name,
      email,
      phone,
      message,
    },
  };

  try {
    await dynamodb.put(params).promise();

    const emailParams = {
      Source: 'yashwanth0571@gmail.com',
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ['yashwanth0571@gmail.com'],
      },
      Message: {
        Subject: {
          Data: 'New Contact Form Submission',
        },
        Body: {
          Text: {
            Data: `Name: ${name}\nEmail: ${email}\nPhone: ${phone}\nMessage: ${message}`,
          },
        },
      },
    };

    await ses.sendEmail(emailParams).promise();

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Message sent successfully!' }),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Error sending message', error }),
    };
  }
};


You’re using es modules where your issue comes from the line const AWS = require('aws-sdk');. As the error states require is not defined. You can do something like import * as AWS from “aws-sdk” to fix it

{
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "Cannot find package 'aws-sdk' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",
"trace": [

@YashuTU, can you please share your package.json ?

{
"name": "contactform",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"description": "",
"dependencies": {
"aws-sdk": "^2.1659.0"
}
}

Check this ,This might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js
